# Select All checkboxes on check of checkbox in multiple lists

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

There is a scenario where list of timelsots are listed under days and this data is dynamically coming from server. Now user should select all the timeslots for a given day.Something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neodescorpio/s50ynw2a/7/). I am trying to follow the example on [knockout documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) but on this example header checkbox is not dynamic. By same way how can i maintain the reference of multiple lists ?

```
<ul class="header" data-bind="foreach: days">
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'chk' + id }"/>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </label>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: timeslots">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'chk' + id }"/>
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            </label>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
    function MyViewModel() {

    this.days = ko.observableArray([
        { name:"Sunday", id:1 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:10},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:11},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:12}] },
        { name:"Monday", id:2 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:20},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:21},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:22}] },
        { name:"Tuesday", id:3 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:30},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:31},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:32}] },
        { name:"Wednesday", id:4 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:40},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:41},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:42}] },
        { name:"Thursday", id:5 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:50},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:51},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:52}] },
        { name:"Friday", id:6 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:60},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:61},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:62}] },
        { name:"Saturday", id:7 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:70},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:71},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:72}] }
    ]);
    this.selectedDays = ko.observableArray([ 
        { id:1 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:10},{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:12}] },
        { id:2 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:21}] }
    ]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

The functionality i am trying to achieve is  **Example 2: Selecting/deselecting all items** in the knockout documentation link but i don't how to implement the `pureComputed` function in my scenario.

Comment: What exactly is not working? It's a bit unclear

Comment: I am trying to add some code but some formatting error is not allowing to update

Comment: On checking of `Sunday`, you want to check all the slots in `Sunday` and vice versa? And how does `selectedDays` work? If I select *10:00-11:00* on *Sunday*, does the `selectedDays` have `{ id:1 , timeslots : [{ name:"10:00 - 11:00", id:10}] }` as data?

Comment: checking Sunday should check all slots like in the example and all days should checkUncheck within the respective list. Having the selectedDays is the question. The `data` is correct but then we need to compare to original array and select all or deselect the header checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to map your plain object to some sort of view model that can have observable or computed properties first.

Then,

1. You give each `timeslot` an *observable* boolean `checked` property,
2. You give each `day` a *writable computed* `checked` property

The `write` function of your days' `checked` property sets all of the inner `timeslots`. Its `read` function returns whether at least *one* of the timeslots is checked.

In the end, you create a `pureComputed` state that parses the viewmodels back to a plain javascript data structure. To do so, I filter out the unchecked days first. Then, for each day that has a checked timeslot, I collect the labels of the checked items.

---

Here's an example, abstracted to just `Group` and `Item` models. You should be able to convert it to your own format. Let me know if you need more help with that.

```js
function Item(label) {
  this.label = label;
  this.checked = ko.observable(false);
}

Item.forLabel = str => new Item(str);

function Group(label, items) {
  this.label = label;
  this.items = items.map(Item.forLabel);
  
  this.checked = ko.computed({
    read: () => this.items.some(i => i.checked()),
    write: val => { this.items.forEach(i => i.checked(val)); }
  });
}

Group.prototype.toJS = function() {
  // Define the format of your selected state here:
  return { 
    label: this.label,
    items: this.items
      .filter(i => i.checked())
      .map(i => i.label)
  };
}


const groups = [
  new Group("colors", [ "red", "green", "blue" ]),
  new Group("directions", [ "up", "down" ])
];

const selection = ko.pureComputed(
  () => groups
    .filter(g => g.checked())
    .map(g => g.toJS())
)

ko.applyBindings({ groups, selection });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: groups">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked">
      <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
    </label>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked">
          <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(selection(), null, 4)" style="background: #efefef; padding: 1rem;"></pre>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for this detailed answer, I'll implement it in my sample and a little changing is required,`header checkbox` only checks when all the `child checkboxes` are checked. I'll try that.